# Set MinValue in datetimepicker in c#

Tags: c#

Hi I want user to select dates which is 6 months or higher than the current date but I don't know where should I start.

Please help me fix this. Thank you!

Comment: in window application or in website?

Comment: Please post cour current code - we can then try to 'fix it'.

Comment: In Window application sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below solution

```
DateTimePicker dateTimePicker= new DateTimePicker();
dateTimePicker.MinDate = DateTime.Now;
dateTimePicker.MaxDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(6);
```

Comment: @ShairaDiesta please accept my answer
As per policy 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can take the min `DateTime` value. Try like:

```
 var minDate = DateTime.MinValue;
```